# How do I remove escape character (\) from a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove the extra '\' from a list of strings in python.

For example, if my list is this:

```
cmd = ['a', 'b', '{word}\\\\*', 'd']
```

it should be this:

```
cmd = ['a', 'b', '{word}\\\*', 'd']  # I need this exact result
```

If I iterate through this list while printing each string separately, I am able to get the string "{word}\*".

Meanwhile, when printing this as a whole list, it's showing up as:

```
['a', 'b', '{word}\\\\*', 'd']
```

**Program:**

```
import re
cmd = ['a', 'b', '{word}\\\\*', 'd']
for i in cmd:
    print("val : ", i)
print("whole list : ", cmd)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Elcot>python test.py
val :  a
val :  b
val :  {word}\\*
val :  d
whole list :  ['a', 'b', '{word}\\\\*', 'd']
```

**Expected Result:**

```
whole list :  ['a', 'b', '{word}\\*', 'd']
```

Comment: Printing a list uses the `repr()` of its elements.  The `repr()` of a string with a backslash will double that backslash, to make the result a syntactically valid Python string literal.  In other words, *there is no extra \ in your list*, this is purely a display issue.  If you want to display the list with no extra processing done to the elements, you need to write that yourself - `", ".join(cmd)` would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the string to bytes and then use the `bytes.decode` method with `unicode_escape` as the encoding to un-escape a given string:

```
cmd = [bytes(s, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape') for s in cmd]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really are dealing with an assignment statement, you should know about [*raw strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) in Python. A raw string literal uses the `r` prefix like this:

```
rstr = r"raw string"
regex = r"\(.*\)"
```

The purpose of raw strings is to reduce the amount of escaping needed when using backslash characters; it is intended for use with other processing engines (like Windows paths, or regular expressions) where the processing engine is going to do its own backslash-handling. There are many fewer escape sequences in raw strings.

Your example of `'word\\\\*'` would normally be converted to `word\\*` by the string backslash-escape mechanism. If you want a string with exactly three backslashes, however, you could say `r'word\\\*'`.

Comment: I have already tried this. But it is now working as expected.
My expected result is "['a', 'b', '{word}\\\*', 'd']".
But while printing this from python code, we will get "['a', 'b', '{word}\\\\\*', 'd']"  (Added additionally two extra slashes).

Answer (score -1):

I believe you're looking for str.rstrip() which removes the last instance of the character and returns a copy of the resulting string

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip

So looping through your list of strings one-by-one

```
for i in range(len(cmd)):
    cmd[i] = cmd[i].rstrip('\\')
```

Should remove the last '\' character from each of your strings in your list of strings.